# Django remove leading zero

Tags: python, django

In a Django template how do I remove the first Zero from all the this mobile numbers I'm displaying. In Python I have tried this but with no success....

```
{% for object in data %}

   {{ object.mobile.lstrip('0') }}

{% endfor %}



views.py


def sms(request, incentive):
    objectQuerySet = Recipient.objects.filter(incentiveid=incentive)
    context = {'data':objectQuerySet}

    return render_to_response('smssend.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass your data to your template in the correct format. Django templates are not "Python interspersed with HTML" like PHP is.

For example, when you first pass your `data` in your view, you should make sure that it is an iterable with the zeroes already stripped.

There is no `lstrip` in the Django template mini-language.

Edit: If you know that the first digit will always be a 0, you can also do this:

```
{{ object|slice:"1:" }}
```

Comment: so your saying it possible to add it into my objectQuerySet = Recipient.objects.filter(incentiveid=incentive)

Comment: If that's in your view, yes.

Comment: cool, so i try this in .filter() and what is it called so i know what to searching for? thanks :)

Comment: @Spike I can't really answer without seeing the code in your `views.py`. You might add that to your question.

Comment: view added above. as you can see I just get all database based on a fk called incentiveid. the data returned has a mobile number.I want to remove all the first zeros from these numbers.

Comment: thanks for you help 'slice' works, but as you said it would be best to do this in the view. if you could just point me n the right direction thats all I need. I 'm just unsure what to search for if you know what I mean.

Comment: @Spike OK, to put it in the view you need to iterate through `objectQuerySet` and do `lstrip` on all the numbers, and then pass the new `objectQuerySet` in your context. To be honest, it's really best in this situation to store them properly in the first place.

Comment: Good point frb1, no shortcut then dow! never mind you have been a big help now I know about 'slice' not good in my situation but good to know. again thanks for you help :)

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do that.

- write custom template filter
- filter user input and store phones with leading zeros already stripped
- create a custom object @property returning mobile with zeroes stripped (this one a little bit dirty)
- do cleanup before rendering template

Answer (score 2):

I assume you will need to use similar logic in other locations of your application so why not just add a method to your model to clean the data?  The code below assumes your mobile field is a string.

```
class Recipient(models.Model):
    ...
    def mobile_no_zero(self):
        return self.mobile[1:] if self.mobile.startswith('0') else self.mobile
```

And then you can call the method from your template:

```
{% for object in data %}

   {{ object.mobile_no_zero }}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one method that does work (but is more of a kludge that anything and removes 0 or more `0`s) - **and only if the number can be converted to a float to start with (ie, no spaces)**

```
In [23]: t = Template('{{ value|floatformat:0 }}')

In [24]: t.render(Context({'value': '00123'}))
Out[24]: u'123'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use cut ( it will cut all zeros from number )

or you can use

phone2numeric
Imo its beter opption

Comment: In () i write that it delete all 0 from given number

Comment: I saw that, but putting an obviously wrong answer and then explaining why it's wrong adds nothing to this question.

Comment: Its not 100% bad option coz we can use |cut:":1" and it will cut only first 0
E: its lame code but it works ...